# Is id attribute ki not valid container class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

if yes then check my code. why it is not work?
I just want that my first container design work according
to my css id #con but it is not working properly.
So

please help me.....

```css
#con{
 background-color:#960;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container" id="#con" >
     hello
        </div>
     <div class="container">
     <div class="col-sm-4"><h1> hello1</h1></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8"><h1> hello2</h1></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you asking here?

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove "#" symbol from your "id" attribute..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container"  id="con" >
        hello
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><h1> hello1</h1></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8"><h1> hello2</h1></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```